# Shop vac power cord gets stuck in the wheels of the vacuum while using

Tags: cleaning

I have converted the inside of my home into a Macaw aviary with no cages, simply tall 4x4 posts mounted to moveable furniture dollies, then connected with 6' to 8' Elm and Aspen tree branches. I cover the dollies and floor with sheets, and in the evening shake the sheets into a large trash container. The next morning before the birds get up I will use my shop vac to suck up all the wood chips and nut shells from the floor. The problem is the 16' power cable from my Ridgid 16 gallon shop vac gets stuck under the small casters as I pull the vacuum all around the vinyl plank flooring. This is extremely frustrating. I have considered a backpack vacuum, but none are made with a 2" hose to suck up the walnut shells or the large wood shavings. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! Here is a link to a YouTube video showing the issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HX627bYt7iE

Answer (score 2):

Start with the cord fully extended and laid around the obstructions. Work backwards towards the power point, gathering the cable slack in one hand, with enough free cable to allow the cleaner to be manipulated.

I learnt this technique from washing a car using a hose, and ran into the same problem: the hose would get jammed under the car's wheel. The solution was to lay out the hose first to the furthest extent, and work backwards, so that the hose is never dragged past a wheel.